# Marker Subdescription and KmlDocument

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm using the osmdroid bonuspack library.
I set a Marker with Title, Snippet and Subdescription and finally save it to a kmldocument.
When I retrive the Marker it automatically has the title and snippet setted but not the subdescription.
Is it my fault? What I can do to overcome this?
Thank You for your time and help.

```
//loadMarker
filefile = new File(this.getActivity().getFilesDir(), "memory.kml");
kmlFile = new KmlDocument();
kmlFile.parseKMLFile(filefile);
kmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay)kmlFile.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(mMapView, null, null, kmlFile);
mMapView.getOverlays().addAll(kmlOverlay.getItems());
//saveMarker
    addedMarker.setTitle("Title");
    addedMarker.setSnippet("Snippet");
    addedMarker.setSubDescription("SubDescription");
    kmlFile.mKmlRoot.addOverlay(addedMarker, kmlFile);
    kmlFile.saveAsKML(filefile);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Marker sub-description, introduced by OSMBonusPack, is not common in maps APIs. It doesn't fit with any standard KML attribute.

What you can do:

1) Do not use it. Only use the description. As description supports html tags, you could for instance separate with a line-break:
addedMarker.setSnippet("Snippet
my sub-description");

2) Once you added your marker as a new Placemark in the KML document:

```
kmlFile.mKmlRoot.addOverlay(addedMarker, kmlFile);
```

, add the subdescription to this KML Placemark as an ExtendedData:

```
KmlPlacemark placemark = (KmlPlacemark)kmlFile.mKmlRoot.mItems.get(indexOfLatest);
placemark.setExtendedData("subdescription", marker.getSubDescription());
```